# Latest Flutter upgrade causes error: 'DillSetterBuilder' is not a subtype of type 'SourceMemberBuilderImpl?' in type cast

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, asynchronous, compiler-errors

Prior to upgrading, everything ran perfectly fine. This is the full error I have received post upgrade:

```
type 'DillSetterBuilder' is not a subtype of type 'SourceMemberBuilderImpl?' in type cast
#0      SourceLibraryBuilder.checkMemberConflicts.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_library_builder.dart:998:22)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:574:13)
#2      Scope.forEachLocalSetter (package:front_end/src/fasta/scope.dart:424:14)
#3      SourceLibraryBuilder.checkMemberConflicts (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_library_builder.dart:974:11)
#4      SourceLibraryBuilder.build (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_library_builder.dart:1057:5)
#5      IncrementalCompiler.compileExpression.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:1817:20)
#6      IncrementalCompiler.compileExpression.<anonymous closure> 
[#7-#59...]

the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97500#issuecomment-1044083031 this is fixed in the `master` branch, which means you will need to wait until the fix reaches the `beta` branch and is released to the beta channel. Alternatively you can revert to the `stable` channel.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the stable flutter channel by typing `flutter channel stable` in the terminal and that worked for me!

Comment: this does not worked for me

Answer (score -1):

If the following command is run in cmd, the problem will be solved.

```
dart --enable-analytics
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That didn't fix the problem for me (on `beta` channel)

Comment: Why should tracking fix such an issue?

Answer (score -1):

I think the program is trying to read data from the server, but the server is not working, so it makes an error. Check that the API is working.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31450611)